# How to change group owner on a large directory containing locked files

Tags: command-line, permission, macos

The command to change the group owner on a whole directory is:

```
chgrp -R newgroup dir_name
```

For example:

```
chgrp -R staff .
```

But when `dir_name` contains *locked* files or directories, this command will fail with:

```
chgrp -R staff .
chgrp: ./file.txt: Operation not permitted
```

If you run the command with super user privileges it will fail too:

```
/usr/bin/sudo chgrp -R staff .
Password:
chgrp: ./file.txt: Operation not permitted
```

If the number of files locked is small, there is a manual workaround
through the use of the command `chflags`.

Check that there is a specific flag (`uchg`) associated with a given locked file:

```
ls -@delO file.txt 
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  staff  uchg 32 Aug  8 11:38 file.txt
```

Remove temporarily the `uchg` flag:

```
chflags nouchg file.txt
```

Change recursively the group:

```
chgrp -R admin .
```

Reset the initial `uchg` flag:

```
chflags uchg file.txt
```

But this method can't adapt to a huge directory structure with hundreds
of locked files. This receipe doesn't scale at all.

---

What is the basic simple method to change the group owner of a whole directory structure containing locked files, while preserving this locked
status?

The same problem arises with many commands to manage directories containing locked files but I focused here on a practical
and simple case.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example of how I would workaround the issue by creating a *wrapper script* for the `chgrp` *command* to act upon a *target directory* having issues with *locked files*.

Using a *bash script*, named `chgrpld`, I'd pass it the same command line arguments (*options*, *operand* and *directory*) I would if executing `chgrp` on a *directory*. Note that my naming convention was simply to add the letters `ld` to it representing *locked directory*, in that it works on *directories* that are *locked*, or not, and or containing *files/directories* that are *locked* too. So where I'd normally use, e.g., `chgrp -R staff foo`, where `foo` is a *directory*, I'd use `chgrpld -R staff foo` instead. The *script* is also coded to work on a *directory* that is *not locked* and or does not contain *locked filesystem objects* as well, thus allow the use of `chgrpld` as a regular replacement for `chgrp` when targeting a *directory*, if I don't want to check for *locked filesystem objects* first or have `chgrp` fail first to then have to use `chgrpld` anyway.

Note: This *script* employes a limited amount of error checking, enough to work under limited testing conditions. It **is not** coded to handle an embedded newline in the name of a filesystem object, which IMO doesn't belong there in the first place! Feel free to modify as needed/wanted to suite your needs, adding additional error checking if/when wanted/needed.

The testing environment was OS X 10.11.5 in a temporary *directory*, as shown in the listing below, having two *directories*, each with one *file* in it and one of the *files* locked. One *directory/file set* is in the `admin` *group* and the other *set* is in the `staff` *group* and I'm wanting everything to be in the `staff` *group*. (See Testing Note at end of answer for additional testing information.)

The Terminal output shows:

- A recursive *directory* listing.
- An attempt to use `chgrp`, showing its error output.
- Using `chgrpld`, executing without error.
- Another recursive *directory* listing, to show the *group* has changed.

---

```
$ ls -lRO
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  staff  - 102 Aug  9 2:00 bar
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  admin  - 102 Aug  9 2:00 foo

./bar:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  - 0 Aug  9 2:00 foo

./foo:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 user  admin  uchg 0 Aug  9 2:00 bar
$ chgrp -R staff foo
chgrp: foo/bar: Operation not permitted
$ chgrpld -R staff foo
$ ls -lRO
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  staff  - 102 Aug  9 2:00 bar
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  staff  - 102 Aug  9 2:00 foo

./bar:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  - 0 Aug  9 2:00 foo

./foo:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  uchg 0 Aug  9 2:00 bar
$
```

---

To create the `chgrpld` *bash script* and have it available at the *command prompt*:

In Terminal:

- Type, `touch chgrpld` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
- Type, `open chgrpld` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

From the Browser:

- Copy and paste, the *code* below into the opened `chgrpld` file and save it, then close the file.

Back in Terminal:

- Type, `chmod +x chgrpld` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
- Type, `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. Note that on a clean install of OS X 10.11.5, the `bin` directory at `/usr/local` did not exist even though it's already in the `PATH`.

  - Type in *password* and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
- Type `sudo cp chgrpld /usr/local/bin` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

  - Type in *password* and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. (If necessary.)
- `chgrpld` should now be available to use, just like the `chgrp` *command*.

---

Source *code* for `chgrpld`:

```
#!/bin/bash

o="${@:1:$(($#-1))}"
d="${@: -1}"
if [ -d "$d" ]; then
    f=".locked_files_list_$(date "+%s")"
    find "$d" -flags uchg > "$f" 2>/dev/null
    if [ -s "$f" ]; then
        while read -r l; do
            chflags nouchg "$l"
        done<"$f"
            $(chgrp $o "$d")
        while read -r l; do
            chflags uchg "$l"
        done<"$f"
        rm "$f"
    else
        rm "$f"
        $(chgrp $o "$d")
    fi
else
    echo "  \"$d\" is not a directory!..."
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

---

**Synopsis:** `chgrpld [−fhv][−R[−H | −L | −P]] group directory`

- See `man chgrp` in Terminal for description of *options* and `group` *operand*.
- `directory` is the *name/pathname* of the target *directory* that is *locked*, or not, and or containing *files/directories* that are *locked* too. Note that unlike `chgrp` which allows multiple *objects*, e.g. `group file ...` to act upon, `chgrpld` is coded to act upon one target *directory*, and recursively with the `-R` *option*, at a time.
- Note: The user invoking **chgrpld** must belong to the specified *group* and be the *owner* of the *directory* and *locked filesystem objects*, or be the *super-user*.
- As expected in SIP versions of the OS, this will not work upon SIP protected *filesystem objects* if SIP is enabled.

---

The image below shows syntactical highlighting of the *code* with spaced and indented comments for easier reading to help explain a little about what the *code* is doing.

[image: Image of Code]

---

Testing Note: Note that even though the testing environment shown above is limited nonetheless I did test it under a more complexed hierarchal directory structure with many more locked nested directories and files, with names containing spaces, and or backslashes within the filename, without issue. Obviously for demonstration purposes, I'm only showing a bare minimum structure for proof of concept. Again, as noted above, "*It **is not** coded to handle an embedded newline in the name of a filesystem object, which IMO doesn't belong there in the first place!*".

Comment: Simple & clean code! Nice for the limitation warning about newlines ;).

Comment: What if a "file"  has multiple flags such as `hidden,uchg`or `schg,uchg`? Nice commenting in your script.

Comment: @fd0, Let me start by saying I've already said "_The following is an example of how I would workaround the issue_" which covers the scenario of the filesystem object being locked and "_Feel free to modify as needed/wanted to suite your needs_" which covers being locked and hidden at the same time. What I've presented is an example of a workaround wrapper script to be used as a template. Yes, adding a check for and handling `uchg,hidden` flags is easy to do, if you want to. Thanks for the complement on code commenting, I'd like to look back in 6 mo. and know what and why I wrote it that way. :)

Comment: @fd0, Out of idle curiosity I wrote a program that ran as root and analyzed the Flags on a recent and pretty clean, few user programs added, install of OS X 10.11.5 and there was only 1 file with just the `uchg` flag set and 0 with `uchg,hidden` set. However, here's the file totals for each individual and combined Flag(s) that were set: 35270 compressed; 80 hidden; 242946 restricted; 268419 restricted,compressed; 20 restricted,hidden; 3 restricted,sunlnk; 1 restricted,uchg; 467 sunlnk; 6 sunlnk,hidden; 1 uchg. I know `hidden` can stop `chgrp` from executing properly, haven't tested the others.

Comment: Well, it seems odd that `hidden` or for that matter `compressed, opaque, nodump, archive` would effect modifying a file.

Comment: @fd0, I just checked again and the file was set `uchg,hidden`, and at the time I though it was just `hidden` so when removing just `uchg` it worked as expected. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

## 2 shells solution

Finally after many attempts I built a 2 short shell scripts solution.

One pretty basic one which will do the:

```
chflags, chgrp, chflags
```

A more serious one which will do the directory structure traversal:

```
find ... do the chgrp correctly
```

### Small shell: chflags, chgrp, chflags

Here is the content of `chgrpld1.sh` which typically will work called
from find with exactly 2 arguments.

```
#!/bin/sh
# shell script to chgrp a file or directory
# when there exists a lock flags (uchg)

_cn=`basename $0`

USAGE="Usage: ${_cn} group file"

case $# in
2)
        _group=$1
        _file="$2"
        ;;
*)
        echo "$USAGE" >&2
        exit 2
        ;;
esac

chflags nouchg "${_file}"
chgrp ${_group} "${_file}"
chflags uchg "${_file}"
```

### Big shell: find ... do the chgrp correctly

Here is the content of `chgrpld.sh` which will run a find on the directory
structures, and avoid as much as possible error conditions in advance.

```
#!/bin/sh
# shell script to recursively chgrp a file or directory
# when there exists files which are locked

_cn=`basename $0`

USAGE="Usage: ${_cn} group file..."

case $# in
0|1)
        echo "$USAGE" >&2
        exit 2
        ;;
*)
        _group=$1
        shift
        _file_list="$@"
        ;;
esac

TMPDIR=/tmp
_file_flags_list=`mktemp -t ${_cn}`

clean() { rm -f ${_file_flags_list} ; }

trap clean 0 1 2 3

# first check if we don't have any sort of flags thus blocking this
# script

find "${_file_list}" -flags +sappnd,schg,uappend -exec ls -@delO "{}" \; >${_file_flags_list}

if [ -s ${_file_flags_list} ] ; then
        echo "${_cn}: can't run because of other flags set:"
        cat ${_file_flags_list}
        exit 1
fi

# if flag present then call chgrpld1, else plain chgrp

find "${_file_list}" \( -flags uchg -exec chgrpld1 ${_group} "{}" \; \) -or \( -exec chgrp ${_group} "{}" \; \)
```

### Install

To make these 2 shells work together, it is necessary to install
both of them in a local directory which is in the `PATH`.
In my case I use `/local/bin` to stay outside of the system PATH components, and outside of the ones used by package managers (`port`, `brew`…).

Copy the 2 precedent files within the choosen directory:

```
chgrpld1.sh
chgrpld.sh

make chgrpld1 chgrpld

cp chgrpld1 chgrpld /local/bin
```

### Test

To validate this shell runs correctly in every case, I made a test
directory populated with all the combination of flags one could encounter
with all the impossible filenames it should cope with without an error.

`dir-ok` is the subdirectory containing the horrors on which my script
should succeed, `dir-fail` is the one containing all the case on which
it should fail:

```
% ls -blOR
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 bob  admin          - 204 Aug 16 16:50 dir-fail
drwxr-xr-x  3 bob  localaccounts  - 238 Aug 16 16:55 dir-ok

./dir-fail:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  admin  schg,uchg 0 Aug  9 18:59 file-multi-flags
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  admin  sappnd    0 Aug 16 16:13 file-sappnd
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  admin  schg      0 Aug 16 16:11 file-schg
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  admin  uappnd    0 Aug 16 16:12 file-uappend

./dir-ok:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  localaccounts  -      0 Aug 16 16:07 a\nb
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  localaccounts  -      0 Aug  9 19:34 a b
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  localaccounts  -      0 Aug  9 19:34 a'b
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  localaccounts  -      0 Aug 16 16:46 a\\b
drwxr-xr-x  2 bob  localaccounts  uchg 272 Aug 16 16:39 subdir

./dir-ok/subdir:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  localaccounts  -      0 Aug 16 16:08 file
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  localaccounts  arch   0 Aug 16 16:12 file-arch
-rw-r--r--@ 1 bob  localaccounts  hidden 0 Aug 16 16:10 file-hidden
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  localaccounts  nodump 0 Aug 16 16:11 file-nodump
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  localaccounts  opaque 0 Aug 16 16:10 file-opaque
-rw-r--r--  1 bob  localaccounts  uchg   0 Aug 16 16:08 file-uchg
```

- Run on `dir-ok`

  ```
  $ chgrpld staff dir-ok
  $ ls -blOR dir-ok
  total 0
  -rw-r--r--  1 bob  staff  -      0 Aug 16 16:07 a\nb
  -rw-r--r--  1 bob  staff  -      0 Aug  9 19:34 a b
  -rw-r--r--  1 bob  staff  -      0 Aug  9 19:34 a'b
  -rw-r--r--  1 bob  staff  -      0 Aug 16 16:46 a\\b
  drwxr-xr-x  2 bob  staff  uchg 272 Aug 16 16:39 subdir

  dir-ok/subdir:
  total 0
  -rw-r--r--  1 bob  staff  -      0 Aug 16 16:08 file
  -rw-r--r--  1 bob  staff  arch   0 Aug 16 16:12 file-arch
  -rw-r--r--@ 1 bob  staff  hidden 0 Aug 16 16:10 file-hidden
  -rw-r--r--  1 bob  staff  nodump 0 Aug 16 16:11 file-nodump
  -rw-r--r--  1 bob  staff  opaque 0 Aug 16 16:10 file-opaque
  -rw-r--r--  1 bob  staff  uchg   0 Aug 16 16:08 file-uchg
  $
  ```
- Run on `dir-fail`

  ```
  $ chgrpld staff dir-fail/file-multi-flags 
  chgrpld: can't run because of other flags set:
  -rw-r--r--  1 bob  admin  schg,uchg 0 Aug  9 18:59 dir-fail/file-multi-flags

  $ chgrpld staff dir-fail/file-sappnd      
  chgrpld: can't run because of other flags set:
  -rw-r--r--  1 bob  admin  sappnd 0 Aug 16 16:13 dir-fail/file-sappnd

  $ chgrpld staff dir-fail/file-schg  
  chgrpld: can't run because of other flags set:
  -rw-r--r--  1 bob  admin  schg 0 Aug 16 16:11 dir-fail/file-schg

  $ chgrpld staff dir-fail/file-uappend
  chgrpld: can't run because of other flags set:
  -rw-r--r--  1 bob  admin  uappnd 0 Aug 16 16:12 dir-fail/file-uappend
  $
  ```