# How do I add/permit "staff" to this folder? "chgrp -R staff dir_name"

Tags: macos, terminal, permission, unix, folders

For some reason, there isn't "staff" user group on a folder that I just created.

I would like the to add/permit "staff" user group to read and write in this folder.

**How do I add/permit "staff" to this folder?**

I'm new to all this unix command so not really sure. But this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/248699/how-to-change-group-owner-on-a-large-directory-containing-locked-files), seems to suggest to type this in terminal:

```
sudo chgrp -R staff ./folderName
```

1. Is the "./folderName" a relative path? Meaning for example if the folder is right under desktop and my current directory is desktop, that command should do it right? or does the path need to be absolute?"
2. What does the "-R" do? Because I seen other post that doesnt use the "-R"? Is it necessary?

I'm asking this to make sure that I'm doing the correct thing before I stuffed up. I'm totally new to all this, kindly please be patient and guide me.

Comment: [this](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchgrp.htm), seems to suggest that "-R" makes it recursive. What does recursive mean? Does it meant that all the subsequent subfolder underneath "./folderName" also got added staff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That command should do what you expect/want.

Comments:

- You may well not need the `sudo`.
- The `./folderName` is a relative path, as you surmised. But in this case you don't need the `./`.
- The `-R` is recursive - i.e. it will change the group for all files within the hierarchy under `folderName`. If you just want to change the `folderName` then you don't want this.
- You could add a `-v` (or even `-vv`) which will list all the files as they are changed.

So I would first use `chgrp -vv staff folderName` or `chgrp -R -vv staff folderName` depending whether you want to change the whole hierarchy under `folderName`.

You can get the detail on any Terminal command using the `man` program. For example `man chgrp`.

Be careful if there are any symbolic links, aliases, etc. in the folder.

Make sure of your backup before using new terminal commands - just in case!